# Back Button isn't showing

Tags: android

I've just followed answers from this site and but they doesn't work for me. I am gonna have few activities and I want to have a back button on the action bar but it doesn't seems to appear. I am using API 16 for minimum sdk and I've set the parent Activity to the secondary activity.

Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_options) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`, not `setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Not sure what the latter is anyway.

You missed setting `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)`. `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` is not enough.

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```